# Oracle plsql store 2 values from same column in 2 different variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My table tbl has values something like this:

```
+-------+
|name   |
+-------+
|n1     |
|n2     |
+-------+
```

What I want is to have a single query that store the values n1 and n2 into two different variable in the same time.

```
declare
    val1 varchar2(2);
    val2 varchar2(2);
begin
    select name 
    into --val1,val2
    from tbl
    where ...
end;
```

val1 value must be n1 and val2 must be n2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple aggregation as :

```
select max(name), min(name)
  into val1, val2 
  from tbl;
```

which also works for *non-numeric* variables.

Or alternatively use a correlated subquery in a single query as :

```
select ( select name from tbl where name = 'n1' ),
       ( select name from tbl where name = 'n2' )  
  into val1, val2 
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it readable you can add 2 select into statements:

```
select name 
into val1
from tbl
where name = 'n1';

select name 
into val2
from tbl
where name = 'n2';
```